# Set colour to a sentence?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

How to set colour to a particular string in a sentence to differentiate with the others?

I have tried using bold

```
"<b>" + myValue + "<b>"
```

I think it woulg be good if I show it in a clour format. How this can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of a particular sentence with an inline style tag:

For a heading:

```
<h1 style="color:blue">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

Or for a paragraph:

```
<p style="color:red">This is a red Paragraph</p>
```

Or anywhere you want:

```
<span style="color:blue">Some blue text</span>
```

Even inside another sentence:

```
<p>This is a boring paragraph <span style="color:green">with some amazing green text!</span> boring again...</p>
```

Using javascript variables:

```
<script>
var string = "This is a string";
document.getElementById("myText").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=string;
</script>

<span id="myText"></span>
```

Comment: Its just a string in a sentence and it is binded to a label @nextstep

Comment: Binded to a label? Like a javascript variable?

Comment: I've added something, hope it helps.